# spatie laravel - how to assign role to user when they register based on options?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

Let's say I use the default auth register and when an user registers, I would a role like `customer` to be assigned to it, or maybe `dealer` to be assign to the user.

Is there a way to allow user to choose?

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the laravel default register method in RegisterController like this

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 
        'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
    ]);
}


public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    //assign the role to the user here
    //return to redirect route


}
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: It gives you control on the laravel registering process, after creating the user you have the user instance. you can use that instance to assign the role